# How to create event of Keydown if all the controls are disabled in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi Friends!
                Actually I need to create an event by pressing Ctrl+N,Ctrl+S and so on But on the form load my all the controls are in disable mode and no controls are there on which i can apply these event.Even i used this event on the form as frmLeave_KeyDown But it did not work out. So Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer, Actually Enable the KeyPreview property of the mainForm. and create the function like

```
               Private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
               {
                  if(e.Control && e.Keycode==Keys.N)
                {
                 // code goes here.
                }
               }
```

It works.

Answer (score 2):

a) Please do check if your form is Enabled or not. If not please do enable the form
b) Add the following event and it will work like a charm

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Alt || e.Control || e.Shift))
        {
            // Display a pop-up Help topic to assist the user.
            Help.ShowPopup(textBox1, "Enter your name.", new Point(textBox1.Bottom, textBox1.Right));
        }
    }
```

Try this Im sure it will work.
[MSDN System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventsArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx)

You can even try the other one for reference
[MSDN System.Windows.Forms.Control.KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx)